# Is it possible to put a control in another control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, user-controls

I'm asking this because I access mails from Exchange Server. The body of the mails contains HTML. To display the mails' body I use a FreeTextBox Control. But I have a lot mails which I firstly show in a gridview. But the problem is the HTML in the body which also is shown in the gridview cells. Is it possible to put a FreeTextBox in each record of the gridview???

Any help is welcome

this is the code I use to bind/etc

```
    private DataTable dt;
    private ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
    private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            dt = new DataTable();
            MakeDataTable();
            ConnectToExchange();
            DoorloopMailbox();
            BindGrid();
        }
        else
        {
            dt = (DataTable)ViewState["DataTable"];
        }
        ViewState["DataTable"] = dt;
        //service.TraceEnabled = true; --om te traceren.

    }

    private void ConnectToExchange()
    {
        service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass", "domain.com");
        service.Url = new Uri("Uri");
    }

    private void DoorloopMailbox()
    {
        FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox,
            new ItemView(100));
        foreach (Item item in findResults.Items)
        {
            item.Load();
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["OutlookID"] = item.Id.UniqueId;
            //dr["Sender"] = item.
            dr["Subject"] = item.Subject;
            string processedInput;
            string omschrijving = item.Body;
            if (omschrijving != null)
            {
                processedInput = Regex.Replace(omschrijving, @"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty);
            }
            else
            {
                processedInput = "geen omschrijving";
            }
            dr["Body"] = processedInput;
            dr["Sent"] = item.DateTimeSent;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
    }

    private void BindGrid()
    {
        gvAanvragen.DataSource = dt;
        gvAanvragen.DataBind();
    }

    private void MakeDataTable()
    {
        dt.Columns.Add("OutlookID");
        dt.Columns.Add("Sender");
        dt.Columns.Add("Subject");
        dt.Columns.Add("Body");
        dt.Columns.Add("Sent");
    }

    protected void GvMeldingen_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Detailscherm.aspx?melder=" + Server.UrlEncode(gvMeldingen.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text)
            + "&datum=" + gvMeldingen.SelectedRow.Cells[6].Text
            + "&onderwerp=" + Server.UrlEncode(gvMeldingen.SelectedRow.Cells[4].Text)
            + "&id=" + Server.UrlEncode(gvMeldingen.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text)
            + "&omschrijving=" + Server.UrlEncode(gvMeldingen.SelectedRow.Cells[5].Text));
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void GvAanvragen_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        gvAanvragen.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        BindGrid();
    }
```

this is the code in designer view:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvAanvragen" 
            OnPageIndexChanging="GvAanvragen_PageIndexChanging" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
            AllowSorting="True" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" 
            BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" 
            PageSize="5">
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: We need to go deeper.  Can we create a control inside a control?

Comment: Tassisto: see my updated answer.

Comment: @Patricker How can I totally hide a column but still retrieve its values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.  Use a TemplateField in your gridview, then put the FreeTextBox control inside of your ItemTemplate or EditTemplate (probably just edit template).

Kind of like this:

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="HTML Content">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblText" runat="server" Text='<% Eval("") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <FTB:FreeTextBox id="ftbTest" runat="server" Text='<% Bind("") %>' />
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

**EDIT**

Do you even need to use FreeTextBox?  Maybe you just need to set `HtmlEncode="false"` on your BoundField (if your using one).  By default the GridView will HtmlEncode all text before displaying it, for security reasons.

**EDIT 2**
Note I set `AutoGenerateColumns="false"` and added the three columns.  I left out the message id, but you can add it back in by adding another BoundField like the ones already there.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvAanvragen" 
        OnPageIndexChanging="GvAanvragen_PageIndexChanging" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
        AllowSorting="True" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" 
        BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" 
        PageSize="5" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Subject" DataField="Subject" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Body" DataField="Body" HtmlEncode="false" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Sent" DataField="Sent" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: @Massimo Tassisto: can you post your designer code for the GridView?

Comment: Have you seen the code? I directly bind data into my gridview programmatically. So I don't think this will work

Comment: I don't know how to use stackoverflow. If you can edit my question you will see it

Comment: @Massimo Tassisto: Updated answer, also fixed the code formatting in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can show whatever you want in a gridview by using template fields: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should be able to add a control within a cell in the gridview for each row in the grid.  You need to provide more information on how you are building the gridview before we can help further.  Can we see some examples?